# Python to create dict keys path similarly to mkdir -p

Tags: python, json, dictionary

Let's say we have a dict parsed from json and we read values from it from the keys in the form of key path `path-to.my.keys`

```
my_dict['path-to']['my']['keys']
```

In file system we have `mkdir -p` to create such path if it not exists.

In python, do we have such similar syntax/function to create `key path` for dict aka **default empty dict for missing keys**? My [google search](https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&client=ubuntu&hs=dwJ&channel=fs&sxsrf=ALeKk02LPelLjo-aVgaDmmcc3B-sqTsbCg%3A1584945040652&ei=kFd4XqmtJ4Tb9QPo75f4BA&q=python%20to%20create%20dict%20keys%20path%20similaryly%20to%20mkdir%20-p&oq=python%20to%20create%20dict%20keys%20path%20similaryly%20to%20mkdir%20-p&gs_l=psy-ab.3...27854.27854..28123...0.1..0.63.63.1......0....2j1..gws-wiz.......0i71.AFpCiD2cZac&ved=0ahUKEwiptYux_K_oAhWEbX0KHej3BU8Q4dUDCAo&uact=5) results not very helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## TLDR

You can use `dict.setdefault` or `collections.defaultdict`.

```py
def make_path(d: dict, *paths: str) -> None:
    for key in paths:
        d = d.setdefault(key, {})

make_path(my_dict, 'path-to', 'my', 'keys')
assert my_dict['path-to']['my']['keys'] is not None
```

## Full details

#### Solution 1. `dict.setdefault`:

```py
my_dict.setdefault('path-to', {}).setdefault('my', {}).setdefault('keys', {})
```

Pros:

- `my_dict` is normal `dict`
- making dict happens only explicitly
- No restrict of depth

Cons:

- You should call `setdefault` method every use cases.

---

#### Solution 2. `collections.defaultdict`:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

my_dict = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(dict)))
my_dict['path-to']['my']['keys']
```

Pros:

- You don't need to call *checking existence* at all.

Cons:

- Making dictionary happens implicitly.
- `my_dict` is not pure `dict`.
- You have depth limit by definition of `my_dict`.

---

#### Solution 3. advanced from solution 1: Make your own function

```py
def make_path(my_dict: dict, *paths: str) -> dict:
    while paths:
        key, *paths = paths
        my_dict = my_dict.setdefault(key, {})
    return my_dict


test = {'path-to': {'test': 1}}
print(test)

make_path(test, 'path-to', 'my', 'keys')['test2'] = 4
print(test)

print(make_path(test))  # It's okay even no paths passed
```

output:

```py
{'path-to': {'test': 1}}
{'path-to': {'test': 1, 'my': {'keys': {'test2': 4}}}}
{'path-to': {'test': 1, 'my': {'keys': {'test2': 4}}}}
```

---

#### Solution 4. advanced from solution 2: Make your own class

```py
class MyDefaultDict(dict):
    def __missing__(self, key):
        self[key] = MyDefaultDict()
        return self[key]


my_dict = MyDefaultDict()
print(my_dict)
my_dict['path-to']['my']['keys'] = 'hello'
print(my_dict)
```

output:

```
{}
{'path-to': {'my': {'keys': 'hello'}}}
```

---

#### Conclusion

I think that **solution 3** is most similar to your need, but you can use any other options if it fits to your case.

---

#### Append

> How about in Solution 4 we have dict :d already parsed from a json? Your solution starts from MyDefaultDict() type not from what returned from jsons.loads()

If you can edit `json.loads` part, then try:

```py
import json


class MyDefaultDict(dict):
    def __missing__(self, key):
        self[key] = MyDefaultDict()
        return self[key]


data = '{"path-to": {"my": {"keys": "hello"}}}'
my_dict = json.loads(data, object_pairs_hook=MyDefaultDict)
print(type(my_dict))
```

output:

```
<class '__main__.MyDefaultDict'>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. How about in Solution 4 we have dict :d already parsed from a json? Your solution starts from MyDefaultDict() type not from what returned from jsons.loads()

Comment: Yes solution 3 meets my need as we can have `my_dict=json.loads()` and then call `d=make_path(d)`

Comment: @NamGVU I append how to make `MyDefaultDict` from `json.loads` into my answer.

Comment: Uploaded my test code - **test0** as yours pass though **test1** failed please have a look when you can https://github.com/namgivu/python-start/blob/mkdir_json/tests/test_mkdir_json.py#L17

Comment: Oh, my `make_path` returns its most deep path. For example, `make_path(d, 'path-to')` returns `d['path-to']`. So you should not assign it to `d` again.

Comment: Uploaded my test code - **test0** as yours pass though **test1** failed please have a look when you can. Solution as test0c and test0d. https://github.com/namgivu/python-start/blob/mkdir_json/tests/test_mkdir_json.py

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.

Answer (score 3):

There's the recursive `defaultdict` trick that allows you to set values at random paths down a nested structure without explicitly creating the path:

```
import json
from collections import defaultdict

nested = lambda: defaultdict(nested)

d = nested()
d['path']['to']['nested']['key'] = 'value'

print(json.dumps(d))
# {"path": {"to": {"nested": {"key": "value"}}}}
```

Non-existing keys will return empty defaultdicts.

Comment: Thanks a lot. How about we have dict :d already parsed from a json? Your solution starts from nest() type not from what returned from jsons.loads()

Comment: According to [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations), it is recommended to use `def nested: return defaultdict(nested)` instead of `nested = lambda: defaultdict(nested)`.

Comment: You should not override `nested` after lambda creation.

Answer (score 1):

> In python, do we have such similar syntax/function to create key path for dict? My google search results not very helpful.

Python doesn't have "keypath" syntax in the style of clojure & friends no. It can handle this specific case at some runtime cost for the convenience using the `setdefault` method though: `dict.setdefault(key, default)` will return the value for the key *after having set it if it was missing* so `my_dict.setdefault('path-to', {}).setdefault('my', {}).setdefault('keys', ???)` would access the specified path, setting dicts where they are missing.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to your question -- YES.

In python you can use `subprocess` module to execute all the commands you generally do on a system.

You can execute same `mkdir -p` command from python for creating a nested directory usinf `subprocess.Popen`.

Here is how you can do that :

```
import subprocess

# Create a string of nested directory path.
path_from_dict_keys = "dir1/dir2/dir3"

temp = subprocess.Popen(['mkdir', '-p', path_from_dict_keys], stdout = subprocess.PIPE) 

# we use the communicate function to fetch the output 
output = str(temp.communicate())
```

Comment: OP's question is not about file system. It's about dictionary.

Comment: Now it looks confusing a little bit. He asked if there is something similar to `mkdir -p`.

Comment: He said "In python, do we have such similar syntax/function to create key path for **dict**?"

Comment: He said "In file system we have mkdir -p to create such path if it not exists.

In python, do we have such similar syntax/function to create key path for dict?"   . And I also admitted its confusing now. `mkdir -p` is used for creating nested directories. We still have to provide the string like `'path-to'/my'/keys'`. So i thought he must have figured out way to get this string from dict keys.

Comment: I look for creating keys path in dict not in file system. Thanks any way.