# default dictionary object with defaults

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a config file that I load up

```
{
    "options": {
        "4c2df1d2257211ec955994de8067dc8b": {
            "option 1": "1",
            "option 2": "5",
            "option 3": [
                1,
                2
            ],
            "option 4": {
                "name": "chris",
                "age": "10"
            }
        },
        "0b093f79ba0f480db3518ea3dbb93f88": {
            "option 1": "3",
            "option 2": "1",
            "option 3": [
                4,
                5
            ],
            "option 4": {
                "name": "bob",
                "age": "40"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If at a later date I add a new option, is it possible to make sure that the new option exists if the older config file doesn't contain it? Without having to check, and with a default value?

So that if I try `options["4c2df1d2257211ec955994de8067dc8b"]["option 5"].append("6")`, I wont get an error that it doesn't exist.

When I load the config I could check if all of the options exist and create them if they don't, but is there not a more automatic way?

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: Have a look at [setdefault](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply! Yes I saw that and thats what I am using. That's one step up from seeing if the key exists though, I was wondering is there was a way of applying a template over the loaded dict. A more stripped down basic way.

Comment: Does this help: [Python to create dict keys path similarly to mkdir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60808884/python-to-create-dict-keys-path-similarly-to-mkdir-p)?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a quick check to see if option5 exists already or not by using "in". Please see the example below:

```
if "option5" in options["4c2df1d2257211ec955994de8067dc8b"]:
    options["4c2df1d2257211ec955994de8067dc8b"]["option5"] = []
options["4c2df1d2257211ec955994de8067dc8b"]["option5"].append(6)
```

Adding this check with if will ensure that you will never have a scenario where "option5" key doesn't exist.